# What's the Jordan form of $J^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form

$$J^2=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

What's the Jordan form of $J^2$?

I know that it has two blocks and $2$ independent eigenvectors.

So it could be 
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
\text{ or } 
\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

But why can't the Jordan chain have the length of $4$ and $1$?

Comment: Why do you write $J^2$ for your matrix, and not just $A$?

Comment: This is part of a bigger question involving J.

Comment: In fact there is a general theory that can work out the Jordan form of $J^m$ where $J$ is any Jordan block with diagonal elements zero. As explained in this theory, the resulting Jordan form only depends on $m$ and the size of $J$, up to permutation of Jordan blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have characteristic polynomial $P(x)=x^5$ and minimal polynomial $m(x)=x^3$. This tells you there is a Jordan block for the eigenvalue $0$ of size $3$ (the multiplicity of the eigenvalue as a root of the minimal polynomial). This eliminates the $4$ and $1$ option you are worried about.

Indeed you have two options up to permutation of the blocks, either a $3$ block and $2$ blocks of size $1$, or a $3$ block and a $2$ block.

Comment: Why "either a $3$ block and $2$ blocks of size $1$" is it correct ? $J^2$ has $2$  independent eigenvectors so there $2$ jordan blocks, am i wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Nice question! Here's another perspective:

You have an ordered basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^{5}$ such that $Jv_{5} = v_{4}$, $Jv_{4} = v_{3}$, $Jv_3 = v_{2}$, $Jv_2 = v_{1}, Jv_{1} = 0$. This is called a cycle of generalized eigenvectors.

If you consider $J^{2}$, you get two cycles:

$$J^{2}v_{5} = v_{3}; \quad J^{2}v_{3} = v_{1}; \quad J^{2}v_{1} = 0$$

$$J^{2}v_{4} = v_{2}; \quad J^{2}v_{2} = 0$$

One cycle has length 3 and the other has length 2, meaning the Jordan form has a block of size 3 and a block of size 2. Also, $\{v_1,v_3,v_5,v_2,v_4\}$ is a Jordan basis for $J^{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

"But why can't the Jordan chain have the length of 4 and 1?" Because the nilpotency degree of your matrix $A=J^2$ is $3$, so $A^3=0$. But a $5\times 5$-matrix $B$ with full Jordan block does not satisfy $B^3=0$.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by the nilpotency degree? How's it related to the Jordan chain length? I only found information about nilpotency matrix online.

Comment: I mean the smallest positive integer $k$ with $A^k=0$. This is an invariant. For your matrix it is $3$, but for a matrix with Jordan chain $4$ it is not.

Answer (score 1):

My first answer would have been any of the three existing answers. But here is another take. The Jordan form is unique up to permutation of the blocks. So if we achieve a Jordan form via similarities, it will the **the** Jordan form.

One particular case of similarity is to conjugate with permutation matrices. The net effect of conjugating with a transposition is to exchange both the row and the column. So 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{3\leftrightarrow4}\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{1\leftrightarrow2}\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{2\leftrightarrow3}\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
At this stage, we have the Jordan form.

Comment: Very interesting. Do you think your method could work for the general case of $J^m$ where $J$ is the $n$ by $n$ nilpotent Jordan block?

Comment: Most likely. Note that this idea can only work if you have the exact right amount of zeros and ones. With a Jordan block and its powers, the rank is exactly the number of ones.